# Need to remove bunch of comments from every HTML file

Tags: regex

I'm looking to restore an old site of mine from the internet archives, which thankfully is pretty intact.

The only thing is that extra comments have been added to the existing HTML, which I want to remove. The comments have been added to the bottom of every page and is as follows,

```
<!--
 FILE ARCHIVED ON 15:22:46 Jan 15, 2011 AND RETRIEVED FROM THE
 INTERNET ARCHIVE ON 11:36:37 Jul 11, 2014.
 JAVASCRIPT APPENDED BY WAYBACK MACHINE, COPYRIGHT INTERNET ARCHIVE.

 ALL OTHER CONTENT MAY ALSO BE PROTECTED BY COPYRIGHT (17 U.S.C.
 SECTION 108(a)(3)).
-->
```

I've read over here that what I'm trying to do can be accomplished using regular expressions, but since I'm new to it I'd like some help.

This is all I've got after struggling for over 3 hours,

```
<!--(\s)*FILE ARCHIVED
```

I have got no clue on how to end it.

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Match and replace the following regex with empty strings:

```
/<!--.+?-->/s
```

[View a live regex demo.](http://regex101.com/r/bZ8uB8/1)

Regular expression visualization:

[image: vis]

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would match only the comment section. Then you could remove the matched section easily.

```
/<!--\s*FILE ARCHIVED(?:[^\n]*[\n][^\n]*)*?-->/m
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zN2vG6/7)

**OR**

With the `s`(DOTALL) modifier,

```
/<!--\s*FILE ARCHIVED(?:(?!-->).)*-->/sg
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zN2vG6/9)

Answer (score 1):

The Internet Archive allows us to retrieve the raw version of web pages. For example, if you have this URL (https://web.archive.org/web/20170204063743/http://john.smith@example.org/), replace the timestamp 20170204063743 with 20170204063743id_ (so the modified URL will look like https://web.archive.org/web/20170204063743id_/http://john.smith@example.org/) then you will get the original HTML without any additional comments added by the Internet Archive.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
preg_replace("/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/", "", $input_lines);
```

[demo link](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/5XA)

It will only keep the text "HTML content goes here" with the content below:

```
HTML content goes here

<!--
 FILE ARCHIVED ON 15:22:46 Jan 15, 2011 AND RETRIEVED FROM THE
 INTERNET ARCHIVE ON 11:36:37 Jul 11, 2014.
 JAVASCRIPT APPENDED BY WAYBACK MACHINE, COPYRIGHT INTERNET ARCHIVE.

 ALL OTHER CONTENT MAY ALSO BE PROTECTED BY COPYRIGHT (17 U.S.C.
 SECTION 108(a)(3)).
-->
```

Comment: Well it looks like that would remove any HTML comment, and from what I understand, McKreg only wants to remove "FILE ARCHIVED ON etc." comments, or am I mistaken ?

Comment: No, it will not. It only removes the comment <!-- -->, you can try the link and add some html tags to check, and select the function preg_replace on the sample link.

Comment: Oh right. I must admit I don't understand why. Must work on my regexp skills a bit more, I guess.

Comment: Well in fact I'm not so sure. Have a look at this : http://regex101.com/r/gO6fM1/1. It looks like only the first HTML comment matches (no matter if it's the "file archived on..." comment or any other one). But it matches any HTML comment, not only the particular one McKreg intends to target.

Comment: You are right. It matched any comments. However, I used it together with preg_replace or preg_match_all("/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/", $input_lines, $output_array); 


You can see at http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/5XE and it can filter out all comments, not only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this :

```
<!--(\s)*FILE ARCHIVED(\s|.)*-->
```

[View a live demo](http://regex101.com/r/eM6hA0/1)